# Cassandra table data distribution issues

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0

I have a cluster with 3 nodes.
I have a table

```
    ref text,
    date text,
    time timeuuid,
    id uuid,
    crid int,
    money decimal,
    site_url text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((ref, date), time, id)
```

I thought as the date will change so the distribution among the nodes will be fairly equal. But its not. One node has 43G of data while the other one has 101G. How can I rectify this situation. Also I have a timeuuid and a normal uuid. Do I need both?(I just had both uuids so collision wont happen as I need to log a lot of requests in a second).

Comment: What is the cardinality (uniqueness) of `ref`?

Comment: Some ref urls are a lot more then the others e.g count for yahoo.com might be 500000 and google.com 500. That's why I had this idea to have a date too as a partition key. The next day yahoo.com might go to some other node and in the long run the distribution would be equal.

Comment: How many days do you have?  I'm wondering why it is clustering like that.  If you have three nodes (not using replication?) how much data is on the third (you only mention 43G and 101G)?  What do the dates represent?  If they are not represenetative (i.e. it is the date you insert data and you inserted a huge batch on one day) that might cause it.  You could go down to hour or minute also, or [create a separate partition column to spread out your data](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/advanced-time-series-with-cassandra).  Lastly no, a timeuuid is unique, there's no need for a separate id.

Comment: On second thought, it may depend on how your timeuuid is generated.  For instance now() in Cassandra seems to comply with the spec and use the MAC, and it says they are guaranteed to be unique so it should be fine.  You must be generating your own though if you specify the time so you need to ensure their uniqueness yourself.  The spec should guarantee down to 100ns (1/10th microsecond) resolution for the time component.  One option would be to replace the 48 bit MAC of the uuid with 32 bits of random and a 16 bit sequence you generate if you are inserting lots of records for the same time.

Comment: Looks like [cassandra](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/UUIDGen.java) uses a safe method to create unique ids by incrementing the time portion if it has already generated one with the same time.  If you are generating multiple records that may have the same time you need to ensure their uniqueness yourself.

Comment: I have a TTL of 3 days and gc_grace of 0. Date (string) helps me to query result. I only want data for yesterday so dates comes in handy. To filter data (where date='2015-05-21' etc). I think I need to look at how uuid is being generated in my java code when I insert the data. I will definitely try your suggestion and will edit the post for results.

Comment: I just realized uuid's cant be the issue as they are just the clustering keys. The problem is with the primary keys. They end up on the same node. I am going to change the second primary key to something else may be timestamp. It might help with the distribution.